# SharePoint Online "First Release Tenant"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have noticed in the messages area of our O365 tenancy that Microsoft mention rolling out features to "First Release" tenants.

How can we tell from within our O365/SharePoint Online tenancy if it is designated as a "First Release" tenancy?

Answer (score 4):

The tenant release settings are found in your Office 365 admin portal. It can be found in Settings -> Organizational Profile (https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/companyprofile) and click on the Edit button in the Release preferences section.

Your options are:

- Standard release - Get updates when we release them broadly.
- First release for everyone - Get updates early for your entire organization​
- First release for selected users (Recommended) - Pick people to preview updates so that you can prepare your organization

Answer (score 2):

Login to the admin center using Tenant administrator credentials.

On the portal home page, click on Settings > Organization profile.

URL - https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/companyprofile

There you will see the `Release track` of the tenant as in below screenshot.

[image]

To change, click on the Edit link and a screen as below will be opened:

[image]

Note - If you are already on the `First release` and now you click on `Standard release`, you will lose the "New features" available via First release.

If you using the old admin center,

1) Go to the below url:

https://portal.office.com/Admin/Default.aspx#EReleaseTrackSettingsPage

2) There you will find the tenant track as below:

[image]

Comment: There is no page https://portal.office.com/Admin/Default.aspx#EReleaseTrackSettingsPage I can't see "New features and updates"

Comment: @user14268 - yeah, looks like it has changed now. The url right now is https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/companyprofile